# Is there a verb that means "to alert audibly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

When I am writing programs, I like to keep the methods as concise and clear as possible.  In a class that contains many methods of signaling a user, one possible way is to explicitly create an audible alert.  I am trying to find a single-word verb that carries this meaning to clarify some of the "chained verb" methods that take multiple actions.

The verb I'm currently using is "Audate".  To a native English speaker the meaning is clear from the root and suffix (i.e. "LogNotifyAudate(...)" -- Notify having a very specific meaning in this API), however, Audate doesn't appear to be a real word.

Is there a verb that would work here?

Comment: This is way Too Localised. OP doesn't need a special English word for *"notified audibly"* as distinct from *"notified visually"* (by text, or flickering his computer/TV screen) or *"notified by email/post/telegram"*. He's writing a *program*, fer chrissakes! Just define an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) in the program, wherein one of the values has the description *"computer-generated audible alert tone"*.

Comment: [Sound](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound?show=3&t=1340932298) is a verb meaning "to make a sound." If you don't like LogNotifySound() on the grounds that "sound" is also a noun, there's nothing wrong (to me) with LogNotifyMakeSound() as a function name. Either way, I think this is off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that Chuu's _use case_ is too localised, but I'd say the _word request_ as such is still valid in other contexts. +1 to compensate your downvote ;-)

Comment: @aaamos: Hmm. So you think this question should stand, just so you can suggest OP calls his function *notifyAcoustically()*, or *acousticAlert()*? Surely ELU shouldn't be treated as a programmers toolkit for generating function names!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hmm. So do _you_ honestly think that any question about the English language where the OP intends to use it in programming of some sorts should be closed? Because you're _still_ arguing against the use case, not against the underlying question. My answer suggests possibilities that answer the question, then gives an example of how they could be applied to the OP's case. The former is hopefully for the benefit of anyone with a similar question, the latter for the OP's specific case. Your last sentence is clearly a [straw man fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).

Comment: Aud- means *to listen*, not *to make a sound*.

Comment: This is one of the most ridiculous reasons for closing a question I've seen on any stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best suggestion is to use an onomatopoeia for the sound. As in LogNotifyPing or LogNotifyBeep.

Answer (score 1):

Some verbs like *bray, blare, howl, yell* seem like not-so-hot possibilities; I think it might be better to let *Notify* be the verb, and use a term like "LogNotifyAloud", meaning to notify aloud rather than silently.

A comment regarding "LogNotifyAudate": I disagree that native English speakers will find the meaning clear.  I'd regard "to audate" as meaning "to listen to", but presumably you meant for it to mean "to produce sound".

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
logNotifyAudibly()
```

I'm not sure you really need a verb in this instance. The *audibly* is really a property of the log event isn't it? Also, if the emitted sounds changes (from a beep to musical tone or whatever) your method name is still accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @dave that an adverb or an adjective seems better suited for this than a verb. I would assume that you're trying to describe either the verb "notify", or the noun "alert", correct?

So how about *acoustically*, or *acoustic*? As in `notifyAcoustically()`, or `acousticAlert()`.

If you're really after a verb, you could consider using *sound* as a verb.